# What does __return_ptr do in IDA?

Tags: ida, x86, gcc, calling-conventions

Let's say I have this program:

```
struct A {
    int x;
};

struct A func1(int z) {
    struct A result;
    result.x = z+1;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    return func1(1).x;
}
```

When compiling this on linux with `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector` the result of func1 will be returned as a stack pointer. Can I somehow set the type of func1 using __return_ptr so IDA understands this calling convention? I thought that would be the purpose of __return_ptr, if not what does it do?

Comment: question body seems to be different from title

Comment: rephrased question body

Comment: you're still asking two different things: "what is `__return_ptr`?", and  "how to represent this calling convention in IDA?". But okay, I'll try to describe both parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" with your example is that the structure is too small (four bytes), so it fits in a register and is not actually passed on the stack. From [the Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#non-trivial) (used by most GCC implementations):

> A type is considered non-trivial for the purposes of calls if:
>
> - it has a non-trivial copy constructor, move constructor, or destructor, or
> - all of its copy and move constructors are deleted.
>
> This definition, as applied to class types, is intended to be the
>   complement of the definition in [class.temporary]p3 of types for which
>   an extra temporary is allowed when passing or returning a type. **A
>   type which is trivial for the purposes of the ABI will be passed and
>   returned according to the rules of the underlying C ABI, e.g. in
>   registers**; often this has the effect of performing a trivial copy of
>   the type.

(emphasis mine).

Since your struct is *trivial* and fits completely into the return register (`eax`), it is not passed on the stack but returned directly in `eax`. So there is no need for anything special here. However, if you make it a little bigger, e.g.:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

Then it no longer fits and has to be passed on the stack. 
If you add the struct to Local Types and specify the C++ prototype for the function (`struct A func1(int z)`), then IDA performs type lowering and converts it to a C-style prototype with explicit argument locations:

`struct A *__cdecl func1(struct A *__return_ptr __struct_ptr retstr, int z)`

It seems currently `__return_ptr` is not used by IDA or decompiler and is just an annotation for the user, but in theory it could be used to make the decompiled code closer to the original C++ syntax.

Comment: At least on my machine gcc does pass the result on the stack even with the 4-byte struct (gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0). But the last sentence answers my question